# mypy "Incompatible default for argument" with keyword arg defaults

Tags: python, python-3.x, mypy, python-typing

Consider the following illustration of `typing.TypeVar` straight from the [typing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#classes-functions-and-decorators) docs:

```
# mypytest.py
from typing import TypeVar

A = TypeVar("A", str, bytes)  # I.e. typing.AnyStr

def longest(x: A, y: A) -> A:
    """Return the longest of two strings."""
    # https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html
    return x if len(x) >= len(y) else y
```

Calling `mypy mypytest.py` raises no errors and exits 0.  The purpose in this example is that `A` can be either `str` or `bytes`, but the return type will agree with the type passed.

However, mypy will raise an error when a default argument is present:

```
def longest_v2(x: A = "foo", y: A = "bar") -> A:
    return x if len(x) >= len(y) else y
```

Raises:

```
$ mypy mypytest.py
mypytest.py:11: error: Incompatible default for argument "x" (default has type "str", argument has type "bytes")
mypytest.py:11: error: Incompatible default for argument "y" (default has type "str", argument has type "bytes")
```

Why does an error occur in this second case?

---

With line numbers:

```
  1 # mypytest.py
  2 from typing import TypeVar
  3
  4 A = TypeVar("A", str, bytes)  # I.e. typing.AnyStr
  5
  6 def longest(x: A, y: A) -> A:
  7     """Return the longest of two strings."""
  8     # https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html
  9     return x if len(x) >= len(y) else y
 10
 11 def longest_v2(x: A = "foo", y: A = "bar") -> A:
 12     return x if len(x) >= len(y) else y
```

Comment: Mm, can't answer that then. I was going to say that the type of `A` must be consistent in the signature, so with a default argument of a String, you're forcing `A` in the rest of the arguments to be a String if the default is used, which would cause a problem if a bytes was passed.

Comment: Exactly: `"bar"` has a monomorphic type (`str`), but `A` is a polymorphic type (could be `str`, could be `bytes`). There's no way to specify a polymorphic *value* to use as a default.

Comment: You probably want to use `Union[str, bytes]`? But even if that would bypass the check, it could raise exceptions at runtime.

Comment: `Union[str, bytes]` and `TypeVar("A", str, bytes)` are behaviorally different things @CristiFati

Comment: @chepner I *kind* of see what you're saying .. but shouldn't the default value type be separate from the type "constraints" enforced on the *caller* of the function?

Comment: I.e.: "if the arg is str, the return type is str; if the arg is bytes, the return type is byte" is one component, but the type of the default could remain separate from that

Comment: No, because you are specifying the value that will be used on behalf of the caller. Would you expect `def foo(x: str = 3)` to be legal?

Comment: I believe it would be perfectly fine if mypy would force `A` to `str` if defaults were used. It's the behavior I would expect. On the other hand I would expect mypy to fail `x: str = 3` because there is no way `3` will satisfy the type constraint `str`. That's different from OP's example where `str` can totally satisfy `A`.

Comment: It think it's normal to raise an exception. e.g. `def greater(x: A = "foo", y: A = b"bar") -> A:` `return x if x > y else y`.

Answer (score 1):

*I know this question is old, but it seems to attract enough attention.*

The issue you describe is a well-known problem. Here's [the tracking issue](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/3737).

For functions, this is just a `mypy` limitation (here's why the issue is still open). To make things work without ignore comment, you can introduce two overloads:

```py
from typing import TypeVar, overload

_T = TypeVar("_T", str, bytes)  # I.e. typing.AnyStr

@overload
def longest_v2(x: str = ...) -> str: ...
@overload
def longest_v2(x: _T, y: _T) -> _T: ...
def longest_v2(x: str | bytes = 'foo', y: str | bytes = 'bar') -> str | bytes:
    return x if len(x) >= len(y) else y

reveal_type(longest_v2())  # N: revealed type is "builtins.str"
reveal_type(longest_v2('foo'))  # N: revealed type is "builtins.str"
longest_v2(b'foo')  # E: No overload variant of "longest_v2" matches argument type "bytes"  [call-overload]
reveal_type(longest_v2('foo', 'bar'))  # N: revealed type is "builtins.str"
reveal_type(longest_v2(b'foo', b'bar'))  # N: revealed type is "builtins.bytes"
```

[Play with me!](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.10&gist=7a380e1710011fd509056cacc2b3ce74)

The implementation signature is not important, because it is not visible to external callers. The first overload corresponds to calls with 0 or 1 arguments: second argument has a string default, so `_T` should resolve to `str` when it is not given, and it's what we do. The second overload covers cases when both args are provided.

The reason why this feature is not implemented yet, I suppose, is related to overloads in classes, esp. in class "constructors" `__new__` and `__init__`, where similar behaviour is unsafe. Example from the issue:

```py
from collections import OrderedDict
from typing import Generic, Mapping, TypeVar

_T1 = TypeVar('_T1', bound=Mapping)

class RawConfigParser(Generic[_T1]):
    def __init__(self, dict_type: type[_T1] = OrderedDict) -> None: ...
    def defaults(self) -> _T1: ...

class UserMapping(Mapping):
    ...

RawConfigParser[UserMapping]()  # Oops!
```

This may be fixed too (by marking such call as invalid), but this requires more changes in `mypy` implementation.